# Permutation in matlab

Tags: matlab, permutation

I want to perform the permutation operation on n objects where `n` is greater than `10`. However, the perms function offered by matlab only works for values of `n` less than or equal to `10`. Can somebody help me with a substitution to this?

**EDIT**
I want to check a condition on all possible arrangements of the n objects. I am aware of the RAM limitations. So is there an alternate method to achieve this? Something like pseudorandom number generator?
The procedure I am following is, I take a possible arrangement, apply a formula and see whether the present arrangement is above a threshold value. If it is higher than a threshold value, then that arrangement is saved for further processing. The same repeats on all possible arrangements

Comment: Do you want a random permutation, or all permutations?

Comment: What exactly is your goal? As the Matlab help says, perms for n==11 needs about 3GB of memory...

Comment: I want all permutations

Comment: @Geethu why do you need them all? You probably need to look at your end goal to try and find a way to not need them all at once.

Comment: @Geethu: In this case, how ever you look at it, the 30 minutes you'll spend thinking to come up with a version which needs a few kB of RAM and executes in a few seconds, are far cheaper than requiring 64GB or RAM and an hour to execute :) In other words: the proper approach here is to generate the permutations *on the fly*, rather than all at once.

Comment: Have a look at `edit perms` to get started.

Comment: Thank you. But I didn't get the edit perm part.

Comment: @Geethu Type `edit perms` to see `perms` code. You'll see how permutations are generated